# Ruby on Rails seems to corrupt a constant in a method

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby

my Constant seems be be modified but how can it be.

the environment is rails 7.0.7.2
Ruby 3.1.2p20 via rbenv

Consider

```
module ArrayTestMethods
  PROFILE_PARAMS = [["id","id"],["customer_id","contactId"],["channelId","channelId"],["identifierId","identifierId"],["platform","platform"],["identifier","identifier"],["created","createdAt"],["updated","updatedAt"]].freeze

  def showme
    params = {"id"=>"d1", "contactId"=>"contact1", "channelId"=>"bbc2", "identifierId"=>"ident2", "platform"=>"events", "inheritedFrom"=>"", "createdAt"=>"2023-10-19T17:03:58Z", "updatedAt"=>"2023-10-19T17:03:58Z", "identifier"=>"353860872561"}
    x = model_from_hash(params, PROFILE_PARAMS)
    pp x

  end
  def json_walker(params, *args)
    args.each do | arg|
      params = params[arg]
      return nil if params.nil?
    end
    return params
  end
   def model_from_hash(params, array_map, debug = false)
    #im doing the below as a test i've tried
    # array = array_map.clone same result
    # i've also tried using array_map on its own
    array =  Array.new
    array << array_map
    attributes_array = array[0]

    puts "array map before"
    pp attributes_array
    attr_hash = Hash.new

    attributes_array.each do | arr|
      model_attribute = arr[0]
      arr.shift
      data = json_walker(params, *arr)
      puts "arr0 - #{model_attribute} data - #{data}" if debug
    end
    puts "array map after "
    pp array_map
    return array_map
  end
  module_function :json_walker, :model_from_hash, :showme
```

if you run this once ArrayTestMethods::showme you get
[image: Run 1]

if you run a second time you get
[image: Run 2]

Surely the result should be
[image: Array should be unchanged]

Comment: Don't put screenshots of code or textual data into your question. Add the data as actual code-formatted text. That way, we can try, copy, edit, and improve your code and actually answer your question. This, please **edit** your question and replace the screenshots with text.

Comment: i did originally try to do that but stack wouldn't let me post the question. I got too much code and not enough text or there abouts. If you run the code you will get the output.  Steps to reproduce ``` rails new testconstant``` create app/lib, put the code above in array_test_methods.rb, and then run ArrayTestMethods::showme

Comment: In Ruby `.freeze` doesn't deep freeze the object. So the objects inside the array are still mutable. This code is also just extremenly convoluted and misguided - create objects and methods or even use a Hash instead of doing all this wonkery with arrays.

Answer (score 2):

`arr.shift` modifies the array.

So instead of modifying the array in the `each` block, you could pass the values from the one variable to the other without modifying the original array.

I would try to change

```
attributes_array.each do | arr|
  model_attribute = arr[0]
  arr.shift
  data = json_walker(params, *arr)
  puts "arr0 - #{model_attribute} data - #{data}" if debug
end
```

to

```
attributes_array.each do | arr|
  model_attribute = arr[0]                # first element
  data = json_walker(params, arr[1..-1])  # elements from second position to the end
  puts "arr0 - #{model_attribute} data - #{data}" if debug
end
```

Answer (score 1):

First you seem to have unrealitic expections about `.freeze` in Ruby. It does not deep freeze objects contained inside another object. For example:

```
[1, 2, 3].freeze.push(0) # can't modify frozen Array: [1, 2, 3] (FrozenError)
[[1, 2, 3]].freeze.tap {|x| x[0].push(4)} == [[1, 2, 3, 4]] # true
```

This is not the data getting "corrupted". It's just how the language works and Rails does not change the fundamentals of Ruby.

If what you're looking to do is to normalize a set of input parameters or produce serialized output there are much better ways to go about it.

You can simply create a Hash which contains a mapping of the input keys and the normalized form:

```
MAPPING = {
  "contactId"   => "customer_id"
  "createdAt"   => "created"
  "updatedAt"   => "updated"
}.freeze
```

You then just [transform the keys of the hash](https://blog.saeloun.com/2020/02/26/ruby-hash-transform_keys-now-accepts-a-hash-that-maps-existing-keys-to-new-keys/#after-ruby-28-to-be-300):

```
params.transform_keys(MAPPING)
```

```
{"id"=>"d1",
 "customer_id"=>"contact1",
 "channelId"=>"bbc2",
 "identifierId"=>"ident2",
 "platform"=>"events",
 "inheritedFrom"=>"",
 "created"=>"2023-10-19T17:03:58Z",
 "updated"=>"2023-10-19T17:03:58Z",
 "identifier"=>"353860872561"}
```

If the job is more complex create an object (a class) with attributes and handle the transformation in the setters, initializer or a factory method.

```
class ThingAdapter
  attribute_accessor :customer_id
  alias_method :contactId=, :customer_id=

  def initialize(**params)
    params.each do |k,v|
      self.send("#{k}=", v)
    end
  end
end
```

In general in Rails whenever you're doing any kind of heavy array or hash manipulation you're almost certainly doing it wrong.

Comment: Yeah, constant in Ruby doesn't mean immutable. It just means that Ruby is going to complain a little bit if you try to reassign it.

Comment: Thank you to everyone. I'm sorry I over complicated the issue. In the console define a CONSTANT say `PARAMS=[[0,0],[1,1]]` Then PARAMS.object_id gives 497700. Then if i say `y = PARAMS.clone` y.object_id gives 528900. If I now do `y[0].shift, i get [[1],[1,1]]. then if i put  PARAMS  in the console i get the same result as y even though they are two different objects. - What am I missing

Comment: It's because it's not a deep clone. The arrays inside of the array are references to the original objects. `x = ARY.clone; x[0].object_id == ARY[0].object_id;`. See https://makandracards.com/makandra/478596-ruby-rails-clone-vs-dup-vs-deep_dup

Comment: Again arrays of pairs are not actually a data type that you should be using in general. I would scrap this attempt and spend some time actually learning how to use hashes in Ruby and the methods provided by Enumerable. You basically painted yourself into a corner with some pretty terrible code and you're not really going anywhere with trying to fix it.